# AES encryption issue for text consisting of Chinese characters

Tags: java, mysql, encryption, unicode

I have an issue with Chinese string gotten from a MySQL database. This database has a default setup:

- character_set_database: latin1
- information_schema: utf8
- collation: utf8_general_ci

For the schema I am working with:

- charset: latin1
- collation: latin1_swedish_ci

I have imported this database using an SQL dump.

The tables contain both Latin data and Chinese data. This is a worldwide database.

I can read all of them in Java.

My issue arise when I want to encrypt the data. I am using AES with Java crypto, and return the bytes in a string using `Base64.encode`

Encryption runs fine. My issue is that when I encrypt the Chinese characters the encrypted string I am getting back is far too big (like 300 chars), although the Chinese text is only few characters long.

---

The encryption code is like this

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes("UTF-8"));

String encoded = Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypted);
return new String(encoded.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

---

Do you have any idea why the encrypted value is so long?
Should I handle the Chinese values differently before encrypting them?

Addendum:

When I debug:
If I encrypt this:
桃草夹芥人蕉芥玉芥花荷子衣兰芥花

I get the result String String value = ENCR({FDDabCcaDabp6YSLYCzg/1MuSzt8QPGEEk3ymeAOW5vERBk+oN3bMSUV5bEbocifr216yqUCObrqDjrrhVwGDqzafWVbELpTQ==}_AB_DCD_)

When I call value.length I get 115. And 115 is just too long for my DB.

I think the chinese characters are more than two bytes long?
Is it a correct assumption?

Do you see the reason why I get length = 115?

Thanks

===================================
ADDENDUM 2

The code is:

```
    try {
        String english = "Rastapopoulos";
        String chinese = "桃草夹芥人蕉芥玉芥花荷子衣兰芥花";
        String transformationKey = "asdewqayxswedcvf";
        Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(transformationKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey);

        byte[] encrypted1 = cipher.doFinal(english.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        String encoded1 = Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypted1);

        byte[] encrypted2 = cipher.doFinal(chinese.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        String encoded2 = Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypted2);

        System.out.println("Original length: " + english.length() + "\tEncrypted length: " + encoded1.length() + "\t" + encoded1);
        System.out.println("Original length: " + chinese.length() + "\tEncrypted length: " + encoded2.length() + "\t" + encoded2);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And gives me the following output

Original length: 13 Encrypted length: 24    V4y9u3tNQaH81BAcqi1XZg==
Original length: 16 Encrypted length: 88    KTMAxhqALAlXfjaOLsBlbj7jbqz+8M4F0AlvvUU5OmrvT+D7MGQHseYKm32V46bqyNbHtu91JC4sQ+mVoWp/wQ==

Which is similar from what you got

My issue is that I can't write it back to the DB because it is larger than the max length of the field.
But what I don't understand is why my english strings of 13-15 characters give me 24 bytes lenght, all the time, and why my 16 bytes of chinese characters give me a 88 bytes long encrypted value.

Where does this difference comes from?

The value in the DB are pretty small, less than 20 chars, so I should not have any issue at encrypting it. The result will always be less than 24 chars long.
So why is it different for chinese characters?

Thanks

Comment: Define "a few  characters long". Post a complete example, with hard-coded inputs, reproducing the problem. Also, the last line of your code doesn't make sense. encoded is already a String, getting it as a byte array in UTF-8 and parsing these UTF-8 character using your default platform encoding is either useless (if your plateform encoding is UTF-8), or incorrect (if it's anything else).

Comment: @JBNizet Of course the platform encoding only has to be ASCII compatible as the input is base 64, but otherwise I wholeheartedly agree with your comment.

Comment: I have added some information (ADDENDUM). This is the length of the result string that is causing an issue.

Comment: My tests, with your input, but my code (since you're not showing yours), shows that your input is 48 bytes long, which generates an encrypted byte array of 64 bytes, which, once base64-encoded, give a string of 88 characters. I don't see anything strange with these numbers. I don't know where this `ENCR({` prefix and this `}_AB_DCD_)` suffix comes from. If you posted your code, we could maybe help.

Comment: I have added an example of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTF-8 is not the best possible encoding for Chinese characters as they are predominantly encoded as multiple bytes.

Furthermore, CBC mode + PKCS#7 padding (called `PKCS5Padding` in Java) is not the most efficient mode either as it requires a large, random IV as well as padding.

So to have a smaller encoded value, try UTF-16 and CTR encoding, where the IV is consists of just a 8 byte nonce (included with the ciphertext) and no padding.

---

Example code:

```
SecureRandom rng = new SecureRandom();
SecretKey aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(new byte[16], "AES");

String chinese = "桃草夹芥人蕉芥玉芥花荷子衣兰芥花";
byte[] utf8Chinese = chinese.getBytes(UTF_8);
System.out.printf("UTF-8    encoded : %d bytes: %s%n", utf8Chinese.length, Hex.toHexString(utf8Chinese));

{
    Cipher aesCBC = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

    byte[] ivBytes = new byte[aesCBC.getBlockSize()];
    rng.nextBytes(ivBytes);
    aesCBC.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));

    byte[] cipherTextCBC = aesCBC.doFinal(utf8Chinese);
    byte[] ivAndCipherTextCBC = Arrays.concatenate(ivBytes, cipherTextCBC);

    System.out.printf("UTF-8, CBC    encoded : %d bytes: %s%n", ivAndCipherTextCBC.length, Hex.toHexString(ivAndCipherTextCBC));
}

byte[] utf16Chinese = chinese.getBytes(UTF_16BE);
System.out.printf("UTF-16BE encoded : %d bytes: %s%n", utf16Chinese.length, Hex.toHexString(utf16Chinese));

{
    Cipher aesCTR = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");

    byte[] nonce = new byte[8];
    rng.nextBytes(nonce);
    byte[] initialCounterValue = new byte[8];
    byte[] ivForCTR = Arrays.concatenate(nonce, initialCounterValue);
    aesCTR.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey, new IvParameterSpec(ivForCTR));

    byte[] cipherTextCTR = aesCTR.doFinal(utf16Chinese);
    byte[] ivAndCipherTextCTR = Arrays.concatenate(ivForCTR, cipherTextCTR);

    System.out.printf("UTF-16BE, CTR encoded : %d bytes: %s%n", ivAndCipherTextCTR.length, Hex.toHexString(ivAndCipherTextCTR));
}
```

---

And finally the output:

```
UTF-8    encoded : 48 bytes: e6a183e88d89e5a4b9e88aa5e4babae89589e88aa5e78e89e88aa5e88ab1e88db7e5ad90e8a1a3e585b0e88aa5e88ab1
UTF-8, CBC    encoded : 80 bytes: c109837322fcd5472539bb7cb51dd6841cea744273979cdbed54d9db019747d41b4e784c22f8e6384e92135ff37747797796baa438f26c914dc5ab99b17afc30771e0b18263d2061d971ef54c457c1b9
UTF-16BE encoded : 32 bytes: 68438349593982a54eba854982a5738982a582b183775b508863517082a582b1
UTF-16BE, CTR encoded : 48 bytes: 9c6afe2d8899284f0000000000000000cad3877bee435324ffa671f956781f2838279fe56e811c9ba5bcf98a6cc98a7f
```

And there you have it: 32 fewer bytes. And that's *before* base 64 encoding which will expand the ciphertext with another 1/3rd, at least when the result is put into a column that uses an ASCII compatible encoding such as UTF-8. Note that you don't want to use UTF-16 for the base 64 encoded *result* after encryption (just storing binary - without encoding to base 64 - is of course best).

---

Notes:

- the IV for CBC and nonce for CTR mode are required; if they are not used then the encryption does not offer full confidentiality (and approximately *no confidentiality* for CTR);
- don't encrypt more than 2^16 plaintexts with the same key for CTR using above scheme.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But if I have to write them back to an UTF-8 DB I have to use UTF-8. Correct?

Comment: Nope, you encoded them to base 64 right? I didn't touch that part, and base 64 is compatible with UTF-8, taking just one byte per character.

Comment: one more question. Is AES CTR safe? Previous experience showed me that words with common letters get common ciphers (Alex and Alexander. The Cipher will start with same values). Which is not the case with CBC

Comment: This is also the case for CBC, although you only notice it when you've got a full block of the same letters. This is where the IV comes in. CTR with a random nonce of the right size is secure - for confidentiality anyway. By the way, you're currently using ECB which is even less secure (Java defaults to it). Doing a course on cryptography wouldn't hurt you I guess, just developing until it works won't get you much security.

Comment: This issue with chinese characters, would it happen as well with format preserving encryption? What I mean if I have an FPE algorythm. It will produce ciphers of the same size for "english" texts, and of different sizes for chinese (I guess all the chinese format will be consistent with chinese texts, but not with english ones).

Comment: Depends on how you represent the text in the end. Format preserving encryption will, as the name implies, just keep the same format. But note that you cannot use format preserving encryption on single characters: you would of course be able to perform frequency analysis on the output if you would perform FPE on single characters. I would stay away from FPE for this particular problem if I were you.

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, use `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` (not latin1, not utf8) on any columns that will have Chinese in them.  That corresponds to `UTF-8` outside MySQL.

Do not use UTF16 for anything unless that happens to be the encoding of some source text.

SELECT length(aes_encrypt("桃草夹芥人蕉芥玉芥花荷子衣兰芥花", 'AES')) --> 64; I don't know where you are getting 24.  Furthermore, the output from aes_encrypt is always a multiple of 16 bytes.

If you are going to store the encryted value in MySQL, you *must* do one of these:

- Declare the column `VARBINARY(...)` or `BLOB`, or
- Use a `VARCHAR`/`TEXT` column, but take the `HEX`/`BASE64` of the aes_encrypt output.